# Can't grant user privileges in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I've installed the latest version of EasyPHP DevServer on my pc, created a table using PHPMyAdmin and added a new user on it. However, no matter what I do, I can't give this new user any priveleges... it has none and if I try to update, it says that it was successful, but nothing changes.

I've tried clearing my browser's cache and cookies, but that didn'd help.

Any solutions to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking into the wrong place.  after your `GRANT` command try using [`SHOW GRANTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html) command like

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR '<user_name>'@'localhost'
```

Comment: That's what is says:
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user_name'@'localhost'

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can see the users in PhpMyAdmin two ways... in the "users" area and in the "privileges" area, inside the table. I added the user through the privileges area, and this seemed to work. I had to delete the user and create it again however.